# My NSScrollView is not scrolling my NSTextView (document)

Tags: cocoa, nsscrollview

So I've been burned by this a few times. I'm trying to create an NSTextView that can be scrolled.

The only way I've gotten it to work is by having a Xib—but right now that stopped working after I added a Stack View in an adjacent Split View for God-knows-what-reason.

So what have I done?

I have code for code copied down the [Apple Docs like for Text in Scroll View](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextUILayer/Tasks/TextInScrollView.html) like so:

```
// https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextUILayer/Tasks/TextInScrollView.html
BOOL deviateFromAppleScrollDoc = NO;

_scrollView = [[NSScrollView alloc]
            initWithFrame:[[self view] frame]];
            // Apple Has
            // [[theWindow contentView] frame]];
            // but we are in a sub-View-Controller

NSSize contentSize = [_scrollView contentSize];

[_scrollView setBorderType:NSNoBorder];
[_scrollView setHasVerticalScroller:YES];
[_scrollView setHasHorizontalScroller:NO];
[_scrollView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable |
            NSViewHeightSizable];

_editorView = [[EditorView alloc]
                initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(
                    0, 0,
                    contentSize.width, contentSize.height)];

[_editorView setMinSize:NSMakeSize(0.0, contentSize.height)];
[_editorView setMaxSize:NSMakeSize(FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX)];
[_editorView setVerticallyResizable:YES];
[_editorView setHorizontallyResizable:NO];

if (deviateFromAppleScrollDoc)
{
    [_editorView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
    [_editorView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewHeightSizable];
}
else
{
    [_editorView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable];
}


[[_editorView textContainer]
            setContainerSize:NSMakeSize(contentSize.width, FLT_MAX)];
[[_editorView textContainer] setWidthTracksTextView:YES];
if (deviateFromAppleScrollDoc)
{
     [[_editorView textContainer] setHeightTracksTextView:YES];
}

if (deviateFromAppleScrollDoc)
{
    NSClipView *clipView = [[NSClipView alloc] init];
    [clipView setDocumentView:_editorView];
    [_scrollView setContentView:clipView];
}
else
{
    [_scrollView setDocumentView:_editorView];
}

[[self view] addSubview:_scrollView];
```

What does that get me?

[image: Halfway Scroll Description]

As you can tell, there is an NSTextView. It does not fill the Container as I would like it to.

There is also a Scroll View and I can tell it is active. You can pull down and get a rebound effect—but it does not scroll the document as I would like. This text is cut off mid-sentence and when I add to it, the View does not scroll with my typing—and even if I scroll I can't get to it.

The Scroll View is "stuck".

I can make it fill the entire window if I change the Autoresizing mask to inlcude `NSViewHeightSizable` like so:

```
[_editorView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewHeightSizable];
```

See here:

[image: Text View that fills the Rect]

Unfortunatley, it still does not scroll and the "Scroll View" is still "Stuck".

I don't know what to change.

I have tried to add a "NSClipView" and set the Content View instead like so:

```
    NSClipView *clipView = [[NSClipView alloc] init];
    [clipView setDocumentView:_editorView];
    [_scrollView setContentView:clipView];
```

This does not work either.

Moreover it does something funky to the width and some of the letters get cut off. Not acceptable. No solution yet.

[image: The NSClipView iteration]

What am I missing?

What do I need to try / set / do?

Thank you!

UPDATE:

The Scroll View *does* scroll the document when I activate the find menu in the NSTextView.

Still mystified.

See here:

[image: Scroll view scrolls when find bar is active]

Comment: What is `EditorView`?

Comment: It’s just a wrapper around NSTextView. I touch none of its drawing code.

Comment: I tried your code and I don't see any issues.

Comment: Not sure what's going on. I tried a vanilla plain NSTextView. The delegate I'm using is an NSTextStorage delegate to capture all changes. To fix my problem—I ended up manually calling and setting the frame size and it works. :) Ended up implementing a nice feature in the process.

Comment: Maybe it's an auto layout issue. Is it possible to reproduce the issue in a small test project (a [mre])?

Comment: @Willeke - I sort of have an inkling of what might be going on. This NSTextView is nested within 2 split view controllers. It rendered kind of funny when I used the plain NSTextView. Maybe it has to do with all nesting. There is a slight bug which happens once in a while on resize. Will do that when I have a few dead minutes and see if I can isolate it. :)

Comment: Fixed my funny rendering problems. Getting much better at Coded-Auto-Layout. Needed to add the compulsory: [_editorView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];